# How to communicate with vuetify v-dialog seperated in child component in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dialog, vuetify.js

I am new to Vue.js and i would like to show a login dialog whenever a button is clicked. I moved my dialog to child component to keep my code as clean as possible, so i have a parent component with nested LoginDialog. The parent component code snippets are shown below:

```
 <div class="my-2 mx-10">
    <v-btn color="#004a04" @click="showLoginDialog">
        <p class="my-2">SIGN IN</p>
    </v-btn>
  </div>
 .... 
  showLoginDialog() {
      this.loginDialogVisibility = true;
  },
  login(username, password) {
      this.loginDialogVisibility = false;
      //login functionality
  }
```

And the child component:

```
<template>
<div>
    <v-dialog v-model="visibility" max-width="300px">
        <v-card class="d-flex flex-column" height="400px">
    <v-card-title>
      <span class="headline">Sign in</span>
    </v-card-title>

    <v-col class="d-flex justify-center">
      <v-card-text>
        <v-text-field v-model="username" label="Username"></v-text-field>
        <v-text-field v-model="password" :type="'password'" label="Password"></v-text-field>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-col>

    <v-col class="d-flex justify-center">
      <v-card-actions class="card-actions">
        <v-btn text color="primary" @click="login">SIGN IN</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-col>
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>
</div>
```

```
export default {
    name: "LoginDialog",
    data() {
        return {
            username: null,
            password: null
        }
    },
    props: {
        dialogVisibility: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        login() {
            this.visibility = false;
            this.$emit("login", this.username, this.password);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        visibility() {
            return this.dialogVisibility;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem is a loginDialogVisibility parent variable is only changed to false if i close a dialog using
it's "sign in" button. If i close it, by clicking on a background, the loginDialogVisibility remains true - and i cannot re-render a modal by clicking a button once again. How to properly set such a communication? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Yo, you have to use "emit" in your child component.
You don't write the position of the child component inside the parent component, by the way. You want to close your modal after the Login Button is fired right?

You can proceed like this.

```
// Parent Component 
<template>
<div class="my-2 mx-10">
    <v-btn color="#004a04" @click="showLoginDialog">
        <p class="my-2">SIGN IN</p>
    </v-btn>
    <child-component @show="showDialog" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
// method emitted by the child to the parent
showDialog(value) { 
      // value == true if Login is clicked
      this.loginDialogVisibility = value; 
  }
</script>


// Child Component
<template>
<v-card-actions class="card-actions">
    <v-btn text color="primary" @click="login">SIGN IN</v-btn>
</v-card-actions>
</template>

<script>
methods: {
    login(){
    ...your logic...
    // emit false value to parent to close the dialog
    this.$emit('show', false) 
    }
}
</script>
```